# Are git and svn different tools with the same purpose or are they different tools for different tasks?

Tags: git, svn

Are git and svn different tools with the same purpose or are they different tools for different tasks? I'm asking this question because we have a quite an argument going on in the office with some people saying that git and svn are different tools with the same purpose and the other group saying that those are different tools for different purposes. Who is right? I'm in the first group by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git and Svn are tools for the same purpose: version control. But as all different tools, they have different features.

Answer (score 1):

Well, both of them are version control system so their purpose is the same (to keep track of changes inside your repository).

However the way how both achieve is very different, Git is distributed VCS and Subversion is centralized VCS. There are many consequences of this fact, for example that Git allows you to do local commits and branches. See for example this [article](http://boxysystems.com/index.php/5-fundamental-differences-between-git-svn/) about more differences.